# How to update a local primitive variable inside Stream? (Java)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm working on a code wherein I need to count the number of 1s in an array, now I can do it the old way by looping through the Array but I am wondering how to do it with Streams.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,4,1,5,1}; //example array 
int oneFreq = 0;
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(x - > {if(x==1) oneFreq++;});
```

Now this gives compiletime error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final.

Is there any workaround to update local variables within streams? Because making it final would mean that's impossible

Comment: Don’t. Streams are meant to be free from side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can directly use [count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) with [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) on [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
long oneFreq = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(x->x==1).count();
```

Or you can use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) for incrementing the count using [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

```
AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0);
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(x->x==1).forEach(i->atomicInt.incrementAndGet());
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if it's possible to make java less verbose this way. Like here .filter(x-> x==1) gives a new stream wherein the elements satisfy the condition. So if say, I wanted to get count of even and odd, I would need to use filter on the array stream two times, is there no way to use any kind of branching (using streams), like if this do x else do y?

Comment: there are ways to do it, just take a look here https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors @Little_idiot

Comment: @Little_Idiot If you have `n` numbers, and you count the evens and get `e` even numbers you don't then need to count the odd numbers because the count of odd numbers is `n - e`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch true in this case but there might be situations where it isn't ex get no of nos divisible by 2, by 3 and by 7.

Comment: Sounds like a bad use case for streams in those situations. There is overhead to using streams compared to basic loops, unless you have a huge number of elements and parallelize your operation the basic loop is going to be more performant.

Comment: @Deadpool The code snippet with `AtomicInteger` won't compile. `Stream::forEach` expects a `Consumer` parameter while `AtomicInteger::incrementAndGet` is a `Supplier`.

Comment: @Little_idiot Java offers loops and streams and allows you to pick whichever solution is more concise, so don’t complain about the verbosity of the other…